# Unable to call locally declared scope function via ng-click in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

- I have a directive (Just a button).
- This directive has an isolated scope.
- I want to update the object in my parent scope by clicking on the button.
- But the function is not being called.

This is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9gRPuX?p=preview).

I've tried defining the function in both the link function and the controller, and they didn't work

I know I am missing something very basic. Need some form of explanation on why this is happening. Have tried looking through a lot of the other questions but I still couldn't find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are already ng-click and ng-mouseover directives. Hope you have seen\considered the same.

Comment: @Chandermani yes I've seen a few of them but I still do not understand why ng-click works with a function (declared in the link function) on an inherited scope, but not an isolated scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to `scope.$apply()`! See forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zo1GrfwyQ8T82TJiW16h?p=preview

You need to call `$apply()` every time an external source touches Angular values (in this case the "external source" is the browser event handled by `on()`).

Comment: I think you've used the wrong plunker, but I got your point. Use $apply after setting the data in the click handler. I've also updated the plunker with the correct one